# Clicking a button and detect its status in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am have a `button` like this:

```
<a class="btn btn-sm btn-danger employee" data-emp_id="23" href="javascript:void(0)" disabled>Resign</a>
```

If ajax response success it adds `disabled` to this button.

Here I need to this button has `disabled` on click event. If it has, need to alert different message, or if it hasn't I need to alert different message.

This is how I tried it.

```
$(document).on('click', 'a.employee', function(e){
  var empID  = $(this).data('emp_id');
  if($(this).is(':disabled')) {
    alert('message1');
  } else {
    alert('message2');
  }
});
```

Also tried it something like this:

```
$(document).on('click', 'a.employee:not(:disabled)', function(e){
  var empID  = $(this).data('emp_id');
  alert('here');
});
```

But, both are not working for me.. 
Hope somebody may help me out. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot disable an anchor element, and adding a `disabled` attribute to it would mean that your HTML is invalid.

To solve this you could simply add a class to the element and key the click behaviour on that. Try this:

```js
$(document).on('click', 'a.employee', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var empID = $(this).data('emp_id');

  if ($(this).hasClass('disabled')) {
    console.log('message1');
  } else {
    console.log('message2');
  }
});
```

```css
.disabled {
  color: #CCC;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="btn btn-sm btn-danger employee disabled" data-emp_id="23" href="#">Disabled</a>

<a class="btn btn-sm btn-danger employee" data-emp_id="23" href="#">Not disabled</a>
```

Also note the use of `preventDefault()` instead of adding `javascript:` to the `href` attribute of the `a` element.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you tell me what is the wrong when using `javascript:0` in `href` attribute of the `a` tag?

Comment: It's ugly, outdated and not a good separation of concerns. If you place the `preventDefault()` in your JS code then all the JS is in a single place instead of being spread out over the project

Answer (score 1):

Disabled is [not an attribute](https://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/#the-a-element) and hence not a property of anchor tag

try this way

```
$(document).on('click', 'a.employee[disabled])', function(e){
  var empID  = $(this).data('emp_id');
  alert('here');
});
```